# How to print the actual HTML instead of redirecting me to the webpage on Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am having issues printing my HTML code, extracted from an external URL. 
This is what I did to get the HTML code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect('url').get();
```

and this is how I am trying to print the document:

```
 response.getWriter().print(document);
```

The thing is that the last line of code opens the code as if I were executing it, showing it on a "browser" rather than just showing me the HTML code. How can I fix this so I can see the HTML code?

Comment: Could you have forgotten to set the headers in the HTTP response? If you fail to declare the browser that the page is HTML it will display it as plain text...

Answer (score 1):

I just had to add

```
response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

before calling the `getWriter()`.